# Overlay a scatter plot to a line plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Good day! I have this code on jupyter

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot

data = pd.read_csv("data.txt")

data.plot(x="Northings", y="Eastings")
data.plot.scatter(x="Northings", y="Eastings")
```

Is there a way to combine these two plots shown below? Since this is technically a plot of land and I have to show the points of each coordinates. Or is there a better way to approach this?

[image]

If needed here are the coordinates contained in the "data.txt"

```
Station Northings   Eastings
1   10001.00    10001.00
2   10070.09    10004.57
3   10105.80    10001.70
4   10110.55    9964.66
5   10117.83    9908.10
6   10062.37    9893.94
7   10007.37    9902.18
8   10003.68    9943.23
```

Comment: You could do `ax = data.plot(x="Northings", y="Eastings")`followed by `data.plot.scatter(x="Northings", y="Eastings", ax=ax)` to plot both on the same `ax`. In matplotlib an `ax` is a representation for a subplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use matplotlib to create an `Axes` object, then pass that `Axes` object to each of your plotting methods like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("data.txt")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data.plot(x="Northings", y="Eastings", ax=ax)
data.plot.scatter(x="Northings", y="Eastings", ax=ax)
```